# Truffle doesn't compile but remix does

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle, ganache

So I'm trying to send some ether from a smart contract to a user, but I can't get it to compile with truffle, it does compile on remix, so I can't find the problem, everything is compiling good except this function, anyone knows what could be causing this?

```
function sendEther(address _to, uint _amount) public returns(bool){
    require(address(this).balance >= _amount);
    (bool success, bytes memory data) = payable(_to).call{value: _amount}("");
    require(success, "Failed to send Ether");
    return true;
}

function sellTokens(uint _amount) public{
    uint etherAmount = _amount / rate;
    token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount);
    sendEther(msg.sender, etherAmount);
    emit TokensSold(msg.sender, address(token), _amount, rate);
}
```

It throws a parse error:

```
expected primary expression when the call function is called.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your message is indicating this line:

```
 (bool success, bytes memory data) = payable(_to).call{value: _amount}("");
```

and it is correct syntax. The reason truffle is not compiling, you might be using an old `solc` version. If you do not set `solc` version in truffle config, I think by default `truffle` uses version `5.6`. in your truffle.config.js

```
compilers: {
    solc: {
     // adjus tthis based on contract's solidity version
      version: "0.8.4",
    }
  }
```

solidity version on contract does not need to be exactly "0.8.4". You can set it like this:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why but there was no version specified on solc, it compiles now! love u <3